# How to get last year (like "00/2017") using Razor View in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to get last year (like "00/2017") using in Razor View.Currently, this code gives me "MM/yyyy" as output. Please suggest me.

```
  @{
    DateTime previous = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime previous1 = new DateTime(current.Year, now.Month, 1);
    string PreviousYear = previous1.AddYears(-1).Year.ToString("MM/yyyy");
   }
```

Comment: Delete `.Year`: `previous1.AddYears(-1).ToString("MM/yyyy");`

Comment: @Rhumborl, your suggested code gives me `05/2017` but I want `00/2017`

Comment: Just curious, but how is "00/2017" illustrative of last year?

Comment: Just wanted to add 00 before the year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want `00/` and last year, just build that string:

```
string PreviousYear = "00/" + (DateTime.Now.Year - 1).ToString();
```